# Is there a pattern that covers this specialization case

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, contravariance, variance

Consider this case of specialization, where the less specialized class requires access to an object of interface type, but the more specialized class requires access to a concrete implementation of that interface:

```
class IPropulsionMechanism {
 public:
    virtual void engage() = 0;
    virtual void disengage() = 0;
};

class Engine : public IPropulsionMechanism {
};

class Vehicle {
public:
    void travelTo(const Destination& dest) {
        mPropulsion.engage();
        dest.arrival().wait();
        mPropulsion.disengage();
    }
    void SetPropulsion(IPropulsionMechanism& prop) {
        mPropulsion = prop;
    }

protected:
    IPropulsionMechanism& mPropulsion;
};

class Car : public Vehicle {
    void adjustTiming() {
        // Propulsion Mechanism MUST be Engine
    }
```

The problem is that Car will need to know the details of it's engine, it cannot operate without it, and yet the `SetPropulsion` method accepts only the interface type.

Some legacy code before me now deals with this by forcing `SetPropulsion` to be contravariant (via a `dynamic_cast` to `Engine`). Obviously this cast makes `SetPropulsion` violate the Liskov principle.

My tentative solution is to add an `Engine& mEngine` member to the subclass, and a `SetEngine` method:

```
    void SetEngine(Engine& engine) {
        mEngine = engine;
        Vehicle::SetPropulsion(engine);
    }
```

However my only reservation is that the subclass will have access to two references to essentially the same thing (mPropulsion and mEngine).

Note that there may be many such members in the relationship, a car requires an Engine, CarSeat, AirConVentilation, &c. but a Vehicle must have IPropulsionMechanism, ISeat, and IVentilation, &c.

I suspect there is a pattern that already covers this kind of specialization. Hopefully someone can name it for me.

Comment: Those assignments are horribly broken...are they present in your actual code?

Comment: You could have `vehicle` define a pure virtual `GetPropulsion` that is implemented by subclass that actually knows what sort of propulsion is used and returns it as `IPropulsionMechanism`

Comment: @T.C. The `SetPropulsion` type one with a dynamic_cast is in production, obviously it's broken but it's not immediately obvious to me the gold standard way to fix it (other than my suggestion in the OP)

Comment: @user4581301 That's not a bad suggestion, not likely that I can get a change to `Vehicle` approved, esp not adding a pure virtual (used by too many other stakeholders), but I am more interested in best practice than in what is practical for me.

Comment: Can you just clarify?   What effect do you expect `SetPropulsion()` to actually have?   Because, from code you have shown, it will slice the object passed if an `Engine` is passed (the assignment does not reseat references).   And symptoms of that are often undefined behaviour in later code.

Comment: @Peter `SetPropulsion` is currently being used to set an Engine. It doesn't *have* to be called at all - it could abort and I could write and use `SetEngine`. I'm interested in the usual design pattern for this kind of specialization... Now I'm also interested in this slicing thing you are talking about - because yes our production code uses `SetPropulsion` and then a Dynamic Cast.